# Import statement after function definition -- How can I make it more pythonic?

Tags: python, refactoring, import

I wrote the following piece of code and I think it's lame:

```
def findfile1(wildcard):
    """Returns path of the first matched file. Using win32file.
    >>> findfile1("D:\\Python26\\*.exe")
    'D:\\Python26\\python.exe'
    """
    return filepath

def findfile2(wildcard):
    "Same as above, but using glob."
    return filepath

try:
    import win32file
    findfile = findfile1
except ImportError:
    import glob
    findfile = findfile2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = findfile('D:\\Python26\\*.exe')
```

The functions are defined before the required modules are imported, and the overall structure just seems a bit weird to me.

What is the common way for such problems? How can I make it more pythonic?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you don't use the glob module on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    import win32file
except ImportError:
    win32file = None
    import glob

if win32file:
    def findfile(wildcard):
        """Returns path of the first matched file. Using win32file."""
        ...
        return filepath
else:
    def findfile(wildcard):
        """Returns path of the first matched file. Using glob."""
        ...
        return filepath
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. The decision should be made once when the module is loaded and not every time the function is called.

Comment: You could keep your `try` block as is but then move the function definition inside the `if` block. For my money, that's probably the best solution.

Comment: @Space, I switched it to use Aaron's suggestion

Comment: I love seeing how the answers evolved. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 4):

How about putting the functions in two different modules?

`module1`:

```
import win32file

def findfile(wildcard):
    """Returns path of the first matched file. Using win32file.
    >>> findfile1("D:\\Python26\\*.exe")
    'D:\\Python26\\python.exe'
    """
    return filepath
```

`module2`:

```
import glob

def findfile(wildcard):
    "Same as above, but using glob."
    return filepath
```

Main program:

```
try:
    from module1 import findfile
except ImportError:
    from module2 import findfile
```

Comment: Thanks! The main program does look much cleaner, but is it pythonic to have tiny utility modules laying around?

Comment: Well, if the whole program is really small, I would usually not bother separating it into modules.  "Pythonic" does not really mean much in this context. (Maybe it does not mean much in any context).

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    import win32file
    def findfile(wildcard):
        """Returns path of the first matched file. Using win32file.
        >>> findfile1("D:\\Python26\\*.exe")
        'D:\\Python26\\python.exe'
        """
        return filepath
except ImportError:
    import glob
    def findfile(wildcard):
        "Same as above, but using glob."
        return filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the standard `os` module does it for `os.path` (short version):

```
import sys
__all__ = ['path']
_names = sys.builtin_module_names
if 'posix' in _names:
    import posixpath as path
elif 'nt' in _names:
    import ntpath as path
elif 'os2' in _names:
  #...
else:
    raise ImportError, 'no os specific module found'
```

In your case, you could place the functions that vary per OS in one module per OS, and do the import resolution once for all functions. The difference with other answers is that the resolution is done *once* on a per-module basis, it doesn't rely on catching `ImportError`, and the imports for each os-specific module would be what they must.

## Last minute...

Because the existence of `os.posixpath` and `os.ntpath` is [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), it might be better to approach the problem as.

```
import os.path
__all__ = ['utils']
if os.path.__name__ == 'posixpath':
    import myposixutils as utils
elif os.path.__name__ == 'ntpath':
    import myntutils as utils
else:
    raise ImportError, 'no os specific module found'
```

**Note**: `buitin_module_names` is [also documented](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).